# How to set membersetting "allow member to upload custom apps" in Micosoft Teams via PowerShell or Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We are creating Microsoft Teams via Graph API using a POST request with a JSON body, which defines the most important settings of the Team. But, we are not able to set the Team `membersetting` "Allow members to upload custom apps". The setting "Allow members to add or remove apps" can be set in the JSON, but not the setting for the custom apps.

After using the Graph API to create the team, we use PowerShell modules (Teams, pnp, ...) to customize the team. But no way to set the member setting.

Answer (score 0):

@Lutz Pumpenmeier You can set "Allow members to upload custom apps" from the Teams UI by choosing "Manage Team". Currently, we do not have an option to do this from powershell.
[image]